# Guzzle not redirecting to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-login, guzzle

I'm using Facebook as an Auth Provider, and using Guzzle as my `$client` to deal with all the calls and redirects.

When I use this:

```
<?php

class Facebook extends AuthProvider implements AuthProviderInterface {

  public function authorise()
  {
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' . http_build_query([
      'client_id'     => $this->clientId,
      'redirect_uri'  => $this->redirectURL,
      'scope'         => 'public_profile,email'
    ]);
    return $this->client->get($url);
  }

}
```

I get redirected to the Facebook login page with a bunch of headers outputted before the HTML starts. The same happens if I redirect to Google or anywhere else. Both say something about P3P?

However if I change `return $this->client->get($url);` to `return \Redirect::to($url);` (using the Illuminate/Redirect lib) it works fine and goes to the "{App} would like to access the following..." page.

If possible I'd like to use Guzzle exclusively rather than leverage 2 libraries for this as I'm fairly sure Illuminate/Redirect uses Guzzle in some way anyway.

I think the problem is something to do with the headers being sent (or none being sent), but the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2?locale=en_GB#login) don't have any information on this.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there's no need to use http_build_query, Guzzle already handles that, you can use `$this->client->get($url, ["query" => ["client_id" => "your client id", "redirect_uri" => "some URI"]])`.

Comment: @MikeF, it's great that you solved your own problem. For those people who do stumble across this post it would be better if you could write up your own answer instead as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I've found out it isn't possible. Guzzle is doing a redirect at the server level, not the browser level so would need to use a Redirector class to do this.

Comment: Mike, what Redirector  class you refers to?

Comment: @gandra404 Something like `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect`

Comment: Thanks @Mike!
I have similar problem but this Redirector does not works for me.